# problema de diferencia de horario Python , Django , sql

Tags: python, sql, django

estoy trabajando en una página web utilizando Django, pero me he encontrado con un problema de desfase horario de 3 horas. Al revisar el registro de eventos, noté lo siguiente:

```
sql
Copy code
Current Time: 00:46:59.479495 [18/Mar/2024 21:46:59] "POST /Reconocer_alumno/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11005
```

El problema radica en el desfase horario. Aunque la hora se registra correctamente, al renderizar el HTML, el resultado es incorrecto. Esto está afectando el funcionamiento adecuado de la página.

Necesito encontrar una solución para corregir este problema de desfase horario y asegurarme de que la hora mostrada en la página web sea precisa y refleje correctamente la zona horaria en la que se encuentra el usuario. Agradezco cualquier sugerencia o ayuda que puedan ofrecer para resolver este inconveniente.

```html
<div class="container-fluid pt-5">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Fecha Actual -->
            {% now "Y-m-d H:i:s" %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 order-md-1">
              <h2>Buscar y Registrar Alumno</h2>
              <form id="barcodeForm" method="post">
                  {% csrf_token %}

                  <!-- Nuevo campo de ingreso para RUT o código de barras -->
                  <label for="id_ingreso">Ingresar RUT o Código de Barras:</label>
                  <input type="text" id="id_ingreso" name="ingreso" maxlength="50" autofocus onkeypress="checkEnter(event)">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar y Registrar</button>
              </form>
              
              {% if mensaje %}
              <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                  {{ mensaje }}
              </div>
              {% endif %}
              
              <script>
                  function checkEnter(event) {
                      if (event.key === "Enter") {
                          // Evitar que se envíe el formulario cuando se presiona Enter
                          event.preventDefault();
                          
                          // Aquí puedes capturar y procesar el código de barras
                          var barcodeValue = document.getElementById("id_ingreso").value;
                          console.log("Código de Barras Escaneado:", barcodeValue);
                          
                          // Puedes agregar cualquier otra lógica que necesites aquí, como enviar el formulario
                          document.getElementById("barcodeForm").submit();
                      }
                  }
              </script>
              
                {% if registro_alumno %}
                    <div>
                        <h3>Registro Exitoso</h3>
                        <p>RUT: {{ registro_alumno.rut }}</p>
                        <p>Nombre: {{ registro_alumno.nombre }} {{ registro_alumno.apellido }}</p>


                        <p>Fecha de Registro: {{ registro_alumno.fecha_registro }}</p>
                        <!-- Mostrar el estado de las comidas registradas -->
                        <p>Estado Desayuno: <span class="{% if registro_alumno.estado_desayuno == 'correcto' %}text-success{% elif registro_alumno.estado_desayuno == 'falta' %}text-danger{% endif %}">{{ registro_alumno.estado_desayuno }}</span></p>
                        <p>Estado Almuerzo: <span class="{% if registro_alumno.estado_almuerzo == 'correcto' %}text-success{% elif registro_alumno.estado_almuerzo == 'falta' %}text-danger{% endif %}">{{ registro_alumno.estado_almuerzo }}</span></p>
                        <p>Estado Colación: <span class="{% if registro_alumno.estado_colacion == 'correcto' %}text-success{% elif registro_alumno.estado_colacion == 'falta' %}text-danger{% endif %}">{{ registro_alumno.estado_colacion }}</span></p>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 order-md-2">
                {% if comida_registrada %}
                    <p style="font-weight: bold;">Se registró {{ comida_registrada }} correctamente.</p>
                {% endif %}
            
                <!-- Contenedor para el escáner de código de barras -->
                <div id="your-scanner-container" class="scanner-container" style="position: relative; border: 2px solid black; width: 485px; height: 325px; {% if mensaje %}{% if 'fuera de horario' in mensaje or 'No se encontró' in mensaje %} background-color: #FF0303; {% elif 'registró' in mensaje %} background-color: #6BFF6B; {% endif %}{% endif %}">
                    <div class="status-message" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); color: white; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">LECTOR DE CÓDIGO</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  function focusForm() {
      document.getElementById("barcodeInput").focus();
  }

  function processBarcode(event) {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
          // Obtener el valor del código de barras
          var barcodeValue = document.getElementById("barcodeInput").value;
          
          // Aquí puedes hacer lo que quieras con el código de barras, como agregarlo a una lista, enviarlo a un servidor, etc.
          console.log("Código de Barras Escaneado:", barcodeValue);
          
          // Limpiar el campo de entrada para el próximo escaneo
          document.getElementById("barcodeInput").value = "";
          
          // Evitar que el formulario se envíe por tecla Enter
          event.preventDefault();
      }
  }
</script>
```

Y este es el codigo que hice en view y le agregue una resta de -3 para el desfase de hora:

```
def Reconocer_alumno_view(request):
mensaje = None
registro_alumno = None
comida_registrada = None  # Inicializamos la variable

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = TuFormularioBarra(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ingreso = form.cleaned_data['ingreso']

        try:
            alumno = Alumno.objects.get(rut=ingreso)

            ahora = timezone.now().time()
            print("Current Time:", ahora)  # Add this line to print the current time

            # Asumiendo un desfase de 3 horas (ajustar según la necesidad)
            offset_hours = 3

            # Horarios de comidas con desfase de 3 horas
            horario_desayuno_inicio = timezone.make_aware(timezone.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0 + offset_hours, 0).time())
            horario_desayuno_fin = timezone.make_aware(timezone.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 7 + offset_hours, 30).time())
            horario_almuerzo_inicio = timezone.make_aware(timezone.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12 + offset_hours, 0).time())
            horario_almuerzo_fin = timezone.make_aware(timezone.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 14 + offset_hours, 0).time())
            horario_colacion_inicio = timezone.make_aware(timezone.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 14 + offset_hours, 0).time())
            horario_colacion_fin = timezone.make_aware(timezone.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 15 + offset_hours, 30).time())

            # Verificar si la hora actual está dentro de los horarios establecidos
            if not (horario_desayuno_inicio <= ahora <= horario_desayuno_fin or
                    horario_almuerzo_inicio <= ahora <= horario_almuerzo_fin or
                    horario_colacion_inicio <= ahora <= horario_colacion_fin):
                mensaje = "No se permiten registros fuera de horario."
                status_class = "status-error"  # Agrega una clase de error

            else:
                # Obtener o crear el registro diario para el alumno
                # Obtener la fecha actual en la zona horaria de Santiago
                fecha_actual = timezone.now().date()

                registro_alumno, created = RegistroAlumno.objects.get_or_create(
                    rut=alumno.rut,
                    fecha_registro=fecha_actual,
                    defaults={
                        'nombre': alumno.nombre,
                        'apellido': alumno.apellido,
                    }
                )

                # Actualizar estado de asistencia para desayuno
                if horario_desayuno_inicio <= ahora <= horario_desayuno_fin:
                    registro_alumno.estado_desayuno = 'correcto'
                    comida_registrada = 'desayuno'
                elif ahora > horario_desayuno_fin and ahora <= timezone.make_aware(
                        timezone.datetime(2000, 1, 1, horario_desayuno_fin.hour,
                                          horario_desayuno_fin.minute) + timezone.timedelta(
                            minutes=30)).time():
                    registro_alumno.estado_desayuno = 'atrasado'
                    comida_registrada = 'desayuno'
                else:
                    # Only update breakfast status if it's currently marked as 'falta'
                    if registro_alumno.estado_desayuno != 'correcto' and registro_alumno.estado_desayuno != 'atrasado':
                        registro_alumno.estado_desayuno = 'falta'

                # Actualizar estado de asistencia para almuerzo
                if horario_almuerzo_inicio <= ahora <= horario_almuerzo_fin:
                    registro_alumno.estado_almuerzo = 'correcto'
                    if comida_registrada:
                        comida_registrada += ', almuerzo'
                    else:
                        comida_registrada = 'almuerzo'
                elif ahora > horario_almuerzo_fin and ahora <= timezone.make_aware(
                        timezone.datetime(2000, 1, 1, horario_almuerzo_fin.hour,
                                          horario_almuerzo_fin.minute) + timezone.timedelta(
                            minutes=30)).time():
                    registro_alumno.estado_almuerzo = 'atrasado'
                    if comida_registrada:
                        comida_registrada += ', almuerzo'
                    else:
                        comida_registrada = 'almuerzo'
                else:
                    registro_alumno.estado_almuerzo = 'falta'

                # Actualizar estado de asistencia para colacion
                if horario_colacion_inicio <= ahora <= horario_colacion_fin:
                    registro_alumno.estado_colacion = 'correcto'
                    if comida_registrada:
                        comida_registrada += ', colacion'
                    else:
                        comida_registrada = 'colacion'
                elif ahora > horario_colacion_fin and ahora <= timezone.make_aware(
                        timezone.datetime(2000, 1, 1, horario_colacion_fin.hour,
                                          horario_colacion_fin.minute) + timezone.timedelta(
                            minutes=30)).time():
                    registro_alumno.estado_colacion = 'atrasado'
                    if comida_registrada:
                        comida_registrada += ', colacion'
                    else:
                        comida_registrada = 'colacion'
                else:
                    registro_alumno.estado_colacion = 'falta'

                # Guardar cambios en la base de datos
                registro_alumno.save()

                mensaje = f"Se registró {comida_registrada} correctamente."

        except Alumno.DoesNotExist:
            mensaje = f"No se encontró el RUT o código de barras en la base de datos."

else:
    form = TuFormularioBarra()

return render(request, 'Reconocer_alumno.html', {'form': form, 'mensaje': mensaje, 'registro_alumno': registro_alumno})
```

Answer (score 0):

Arregle el problema de desfase de hora aquí el código

```
def Reconocer_alumno_view(request):
mensaje = None
registro_alumno = None
comida_registrada = None  # Inicializamos la variable

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = TuFormularioBarra(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ingreso = form.cleaned_data['ingreso']

        try:
            alumno = Alumno.objects.get(rut=ingreso)

            ahora = timezone.now().astimezone(timezone.get_current_timezone()).time()
            print("Current Time:", ahora)  # Agrega esta línea para imprimir la hora actual en la consola

            # Horarios de comidas
            horario_desayuno_inicio = timezone.make_aware(timezone.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0).time())
            horario_desayuno_fin = timezone.make_aware(timezone.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 7, 30).time())
            horario_almuerzo_inicio = timezone.make_aware(timezone.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0).time())
            horario_almuerzo_fin = timezone.make_aware(timezone.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 14, 0).time())
            horario_colacion_inicio = timezone.make_aware(timezone.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 22, 0).time())
            horario_colacion_fin = timezone.make_aware(timezone.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 23, 10).time())

            # Verificar si la hora actual está dentro de los horarios establecidos
            if not (horario_desayuno_inicio <= ahora <= horario_desayuno_fin or
                    horario_almuerzo_inicio <= ahora <= horario_almuerzo_fin or
                    horario_colacion_inicio <= ahora <= horario_colacion_fin):
                mensaje = "No se permiten registros fuera de horario."
                status_class = "status-error"  # Agrega una clase de error
            else:
                # Obtener o crear el registro diario para el alumno
                # Obtener la fecha actual en la zona horaria de Santiago
                fecha_actual = timezone.now().astimezone(timezone.get_current_timezone()).date()

                registro_alumno, created = RegistroAlumno.objects.get_or_create(
                    rut=alumno.rut,
                    fecha_registro=fecha_actual,
                    defaults={
                        'nombre': alumno.nombre,
                        'apellido': alumno.apellido,
                    }
                )

                # Actualizar estado de asistencia para desayuno
                if horario_desayuno_inicio <= ahora <= horario_desayuno_fin:
                    registro_alumno.estado_desayuno = 'correcto'
                    comida_registrada = 'desayuno'
                elif ahora > horario_desayuno_fin and ahora <= timezone.make_aware(
                        timezone.datetime(2000, 1, 1, horario_desayuno_fin.hour,
                                          horario_desayuno_fin.minute) + timezone.timedelta(
                            minutes=30)).time():
                    registro_alumno.estado_desayuno = 'atrasado'
                    comida_registrada = 'desayuno'
                else:
                    # Only update breakfast status if it's currently marked as 'falta'
                    if registro_alumno.estado_desayuno != 'correcto' and registro_alumno.estado_desayuno != 'atrasado':
                        registro_alumno.estado_desayuno = 'falta'

                # Actualizar estado de asistencia para almuerzo
                if horario_almuerzo_inicio <= ahora <= horario_almuerzo_fin:
                    registro_alumno.estado_almuerzo = 'correcto'
                    if comida_registrada:
                        comida_registrada += ', almuerzo'
                    else:
                        comida_registrada = 'almuerzo'
                elif ahora > horario_almuerzo_fin and ahora <= timezone.make_aware(
                        timezone.datetime(2000, 1, 1, horario_almuerzo_fin.hour,
                                          horario_almuerzo_fin.minute) + timezone.timedelta(
                            minutes=30)).time():
                    registro_alumno.estado_almuerzo = 'atrasado'
                    if comida_registrada:
                        comida_registrada += ', almuerzo'
                    else:
                        comida_registrada = 'almuerzo'
                else:
                    registro_alumno.estado_almuerzo = 'falta'

                # Actualizar estado de asistencia para colacion
                if horario_colacion_inicio <= ahora <= horario_colacion_fin:
                    registro_alumno.estado_colacion = 'correcto'
                    if comida_registrada:
                        comida_registrada += ', colacion'
                    else:
                        comida_registrada = 'colacion'
                elif ahora > horario_colacion_fin and ahora <= timezone.make_aware(
                        timezone.datetime(2000, 1, 1, horario_colacion_fin.hour,
                                          horario_colacion_fin.minute) + timezone.timedelta(
                            minutes=30)).time():
                    registro_alumno.estado_colacion = 'atrasado'
                    if comida_registrada:
                        comida_registrada += ', colacion'
                    else:
                        comida_registrada = 'colacion'
                else:
                    registro_alumno.estado_colacion = 'falta'

                # Guardar cambios en la base de datos
                registro_alumno.save()

                mensaje = f"Se registró {comida_registrada} correctamente."

        except Alumno.DoesNotExist:
            mensaje = f"No se encontró el RUT o código de barras en la base de datos."

else:
    form = TuFormularioBarra()

return render(request, 'Reconocer_alumno.html', {'form': form, 'mensaje': mensaje, 'registro_alumno': registro_alumno})
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo tu código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.